# Is it possible to apply a style to all (tikz) rectangles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I know that it's possible to apply styling to all tikz nodes or paths, as in the following example:

```
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        text=red
    },
    every path/.style={
        color=green,
        thin
    }
}
```

(Which makes all nodes have red text and all paths have thin green lines.)

Is there a similar way to apply styling to all tikz rectangles, so those produced by draw commands such as `\draw (1,1) rectangle (3,3);`?

I tried the following, on the off-chance it might work (it didn't, hence my question!):

```
\tikzset{
    every rectangle/.style={%
        blue,
        rounded corners,
        ultra thick
    }
}
```

My current work-around is to use a style which I apply to every rectangle manually, although this is a little tedious. This is demonstrated in the below minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    every rectangle/.style={
        blue,
        rounded corners,
        ultra thick
    },
    my rectangle/.style={
        blue,
        rounded corners,
        ultra thick
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % A rectangle which would be styled by the "every rectangle" bit if 
    % it worked in the way that I would like it to:
    \draw (1,5) rectangle (4,7);

    % A rectangle with my custom styling applying to it:
    \draw [my rectangle] (1,1) rectangle (4,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The rectangles in the above would be identical (besides position) if `every rectangle` worked in the way I would like it to or if there's some other way to style all rectangles.

So essentially I would like to know if an actual equivalent to my pseudo `every rectangle` exists.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. `rectangle` is just a path command that gets translated into coordinates immediately, so it's not really treated as a special object. Also, this would be difficult from another perspective: You could have a `\path` command with a `rectangle` and a `circle` in it. If you had an `every rectangle` and an `every circle` style, which one would apply in that case, as paths can only have one drawing style. You  might need to work with rectangle nodes in this case.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Rectangle nodes - am I correct in thinking they are drawn with commands like: `\node [draw, rectangle] ...`?
Do you know if a style could be applied to all of those in a similar manner to how I've been describing?

Comment: @Jake: Oh and cheers for the clear explanation, I can see why it would be problematic thanks to the other perspective you provided ^^

Comment: It is possible to implement similar behaviour through styling `every rectangle node` and using rectangle nodes as Jake mentioned. I will post an answer with an example once I am able to do so. (There's a block on me doing so for another 5 hours due to my reputation being less than 100.)

Comment: @Jake `every circle` style exists in the doc pgf 2.1 cvs :  "You can use this key to set up, say, a default radius for every circle." but I think we can't do some limited actions like changed `radius` with `r` or setup things like `radius= 1cm`.

Comment: @Altermundus: Good point, but unfortunately that mechanism doesn't exist for `rectangle`.

Comment: @Jake In the case of a circle, the path is not changed with `radius` and like you say `rectangle` is just a  path command between two points so we can change nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not define a style that automatically applies to all `rectangle`s. `rectangle` is just a path command that gets translated into coordinates immediately, so it's not really treated as a special object. Also, this would be difficult from another perspective: You could have a `\path` command with a rectangle and a circle in it. Paths can only have one drawing style, so if you had an `every rectangle` and an `every circle` style, which one would apply in that case?

Two alternative approaches spring to mind:

1. Use `edge` instead of `rectangle`. Then you can specify `every edge/.style={to path={rectangle (\tikztotarget)}` and the necessary drawing options. Of course, you'll have to take care if you use `edge` in other contexts.
2. Use nodes instead of just paths for your rectangles. They allow the use of styles like `every rectangle node/.style`.

Here's an example with both approaches:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    rectnode/.style args={#1,#2}{
        draw,
        blue,
        rounded corners,
        ultra thick,
        minimum width=#1 cm,
        minimum height=#2 cm,
        anchor=south west
    },
    every edge/.style={
        draw,
        ultra thick,
        blue,
        rounded corners,
        to path={rectangle (\tikztotarget)}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,5) edge (4,7);

    \node [rectnode={3,2}] at (1,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cheers Jake! I particularly like the `edge`-based solution as I can still use coordinates as in `\draw ... [rectangle] ...` and I don't have to apply a style to each edge manually ^^

Answer (score 6):

Based on Jake's original comment, some searching and a little experimentation I arrived at the solution of applying a style to `every rectangle node`, which Jake also mentions in his answer.

Here is a brief example using this idea:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    every rectangle node/.style={
        color=blue,
        ultra thick
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % A rectangle node which will have the "every rectangle node" styling applied to it:
    \node at (1,3) [draw, rectangle] {Node 1};

    % The "color=blue" styling also applies itself to the text attached to this node,
    % although it does not explicitly have a rectangle type
    \node at (1,2) {Node 2};

    % However it is not applied to this one, as it has a defined type (circle):
    \node at (1,1) [circle] {Node 3};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces (zoomed and cropped somewhat):

[image: A screenshot of the output of the above LaTeX showing the 3 nodes produced]

The slight caveat that this example (hopefully) highlights is that the `every rectangle node` styling is also applied to node 2. This initially seemed odd to me as that node doesn't have rectangle specified as a type, but I believe that this happens because nodes have `rectangle` as a default type. One workaround in this situation is to use a node of type circle without drawing, as demonstrated with node 3.

So to answer my original question - `every rectangle node` (in conjunction with rectangle nodes) can be used to produce equivalent results to my desired pseudo `every rectangle`, with the above caveat.

Comment: Due to the described generally undesirable (at least to me) behaviour and Jake's `edge`-based solution being more elegant (in my humble opinion), I shall be using that. My answer is just to expand on the possibility of using `every rectangle node`.